# Google Docs - Drag & Drop

Tags: browser, drag-and-drop, cross-browser, google-docs

There are lots of posts that discuss drag and drop functionality to upload files and folders to Google Docs, but there are few discussions regarding dragging and dropping between Google Docs labels.

At the moment, we have a shared top-level folder with a tree of sub-folders and files. The problem is, it is far too easy to mis-drag and drop labels (a.k.a. folders) into one another, so content is getting easily misplaced.

Does anyone know a way of disabling this centrally through Google Apps (I've looked in earnest and can't find anything), or in the very least, a way to disable this functionality in the browser, regardless of the impact it might have on other functionality beyond the scope of Google Docs?

Hope this makes sense. Please ask questions if you need anything clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) to disable the functionality in the browser, for Firefox or Chrome (and potentially [IE](http://www.bhelpuri.net/Trixie/) and [Safari](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/11/14/how-to-run-greasemonkey-scripts-in-safari/)).

- You would have to write a Greasemonkey script to do it.
- It would not impact functionality beyond Google Docs, the webpage you specify.
- You would have to install it for each user.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's not an ideal solution, but if no-one comes back with anything better within 24 hours, I'll mark as the accepted solution.